# Is there a way to automatically post videos on twitter using python?

Tags: python, twitter

I've been reasearching a way to automatize content on twitter, but I'm struggling to find a way to solve this.

I've found Tweepy while researching, and although it is very nice and practical, it does not support video posting.

Is there any way of doing this ?

Comment: “*Is there any way of doing this ?*” What have you researched? Surely you’ve surmised that the answer to this question is “yes”, considering all the third-party Twitter clients that support such a feature. What is your *actual* question? What code have you written so far in an attempt to meet this requirement? Where are you getting stuck? We won’t write all your code *for* you, but we can help if you show a good-faith attempt at rectifying on your own before posting here, in accordance with [ask].

Comment: The [`media_upload` method in Tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#media) does exactly what you want.